# Smarty date_format does not work on "0000-00-00 00:00"

Tags: datetime, smarty

Date pulled from database in varuable "$request.date" as "0000-00-00 00:00:00" when display variable `{$request.date}` it it shows correct .
But when i try format it e.g. `{$request.date|date_format:"%Y-%m-%d"}` it shows today's date instead.

I need to check somehow if database's date is empty e.g. all zeros and if it is show something else

```
I used to have
{if $request.date|date_format:"%Y"} == "1999"}
Date NOT Set
{else}
Date Set
{/if}
```

but after transferring to new server i does not work anymore because date is different.

Is there way to use mid or left function to get year? i tried `{$number|string_format:"%d"}` but it display 0 i am not sure if this is from time or year.

Comment: I'm afraid I've not understand the problem. In the database you have `0000-00-00 00:00:00` dates? And `date_format` is not able to display it properly (that is `0000-00-00` in your case)? If so, what's that `1999` in your code?

Comment: please ignore 1999 somehow on old server it was showing 1999 now it shows current year 2011 when it should show 0000

Comment: Ok. I can see two big problems in your code. One, I don't think you can use modifiers in `{if}` condition, two, you cannot nest `{}` braces (you are doing it in your condition, you open one, you close two).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use this?

```
{if $request.date == "0000-00-00 00:00:00"}
    Date NOT Set
{else}
   Date Set to {$request.date|date_format:"%Y-%m-%d"}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to clean up your dates in PHP first by using

```
  $timestamp = strtotime($date_string); //where date_string has the format 0000-00-00 ...
```

Before in smarty you then use the `date_format` **modifier**
Since you're pulling the content from the database, you'll have to loop through the returned content(if it's multi dimensional) in the array in PHP and operate on that `"date"` index.
Hope this helps.